# Use React-Redux To Develop a Login Page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I try to use React-Redux to develope a Login Page and I encounter with some problems.

I want to send the TextFields about account and password to server by AJAX, but when I click the login button, this login button can not get the value of TextFields.

I do not want to use "form tag" and I try to do my best to solve this problem by myself, but I still suspect my solution, so I want to find some advise about this problem.

My solution is the following

TextFields will trigger an action which will set Login info into the next state.
The Login Button will do send these info to server only.

The following is the part of codes.

TextField:

```
class BaseInputComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    _handleChange(e) {
        this.props.onChange({infoType: this.props.dataType, data: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        var style = {
            marginBottom: 30
        };

        return (
            <div style={style}>
                <TextField
                    hintText={ this.props.hintText }
                    floatingLabelText={ this.props.floatingLabelText }
                    type={ this.props.type }
                    onChange={ this._handleChange }
                    value={this.props.textField}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

A Login Page

```
class UserPaperComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleClickBtn() {
        this.props.actions.userLogin()
    }

    render() {
        var style = {
            padding: 20,
            textAlign: 'center',
        };

        return (
            <Paper style={style} zDepth={5}>
                <UserPaperTitleComponent text={this.props.userPaperText}/>
                <Divider />
                <BaseInputComponent dataType="userAccount" textField={this.props.userInfo.userAccount} onChange={ this.props.actions.setUserInfo } floatingLabelText="Account"/>
                <BaseInputComponent dataType="userPwd" textField={this.props.userInfo.userPwd} onChange={ this.props.actions.setUserInfo }  floatingLabelText="Password" type="password"/>
                <Divider />
                <br />
                <RaisedButton label={this.props.userPaperText} onMouseUp={ this.handleClickBtn } />
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}
```

In the reduce

```
const initialState = {
  userAccount: '',
  userPwd: '',
  userHadLogin: false
};

module.exports = function(state = initialState, action) {
  /* Keep the reducer clean - do not mutate the original state. */
  //let nextState = Object.assign({}, state);

  switch(action.type) {

    case 'SET_USER_INFO': {
      console.log(action.paras)
      let nextState = Object.assign({}, state);
      nextState[action.paras.infoType] = action.paras.data;
      return nextState;
    } break;

    case 'USER_LOGIN': {
      // Modify next state depending on the action and return it
      let nextState = Object.assign({}, state);
      nextState.userHadLogin = true;
      return nextState;
    } break;

    case 'USER_LOGOUT': {
      // Modify next state depending on the action and return it
      let nextState = Object.assign({}, initialState);
      return nextState;
    } break;

    default: {
      /* Return original state if no actions were consumed. */
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try binding binding the handler with "this"
 `<RaisedButton label={this.props.userPaperText} onMouseUp={ this.handleClickBtn.bind(this) } />`

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot to add it. It is a bug, but my major problem is that do it have any other solution for my scenario? (My scenario is "I want to send the TextFields about account and password to server by AJAX, but when I click the login button, this login button can not get the value of TextFields, because I am not use form tag")